# canvas inside a div with overflow-y

Tags: css, html, canvas, scrollbar

I have a div with overflow-y and inside it a canvas.
When I scroll down, I'm getting at the bottom a strip in FF, Chrome and IE9.
How can I make this strip go away?

The red strip can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/etipez/2/edit#preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  #container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 900px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
  }

  #container canvas {
    background-color: gray;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var init = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = container.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = 1000;
    container.appendChild(canvas);
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not change background-color of #container to grey?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fSgQN/

Comment: @gopi1410 he's doing to show us the problem

Comment: Interesting problem; can't see where it's coming from. Setting `canvas.style.height = '1000px'` also has the same effect, btw. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fSgQN/1/

Comment: @JaredFarrish seriously interesting

Comment: @JaredFarrish if you remove all overflow it works

Comment: @Mr.Alien - It also does not effect a `DIV` element: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fSgQN/2/

Comment: And `overflow: auto` [shows the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fSgQN/3/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I guess there's something with the script may be..

Comment: I'm wondering if `canvas` has a special rendering characteristic. If you wrap a `div` around the `canvas`, the [space is still there](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fSgQN/5/), but the wrapping `div` does not have it, it's on the `container`.

Comment: I don't think so I tried * {margin: 0px; padding:0px;} no change, gosh this is seriously tricky 1..

Comment: @Mr.Alien - There's a CSS normalization script on those fiddles, so that's already been zeroed out.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I guess this is browser issue, not fully supporting HTML5 tags yet yea? it could be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: block;` in `#container canvas`:

```
#container canvas {
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/etipez/5/edit)

Comment: In my case giving position:absolute to the canvas and position:relative to the container works too. I understand why display:block works but I don't understand why it is needed in the first place.